# postgres bad estimates from partitioned table

Tags: postgresql

A table has been partitioned and when the query is being run against it, it runs longer due to nested loop - due to bad estimates (the tables are vacuumed and analyzed). When the same query is run against non-partitioned table it takes hash join and runs 16s compared to 3mins on partitioned table. Please see the query and plans.

```
select "CT"."YID" as "c0", "Z_ASTD"."LID" as "c1", "Z_AN_ACC_STD"."LID" as "c2", "Z_SCEN_LST"."LID" as "c3", "Z_PROD_STD"."LID" as "c4", "Z_AT_LST"."LID" as "c5", "Z_SSTD"."LID" as "c6", sum("BAL"."BALANCE") as "m0" 
from "CT" as "CT", "BAL" as "BAL", "Z_ASTD" as "Z_ASTD", "Z_AN_ACC_STD" as "Z_AN_ACC_STD", "Z_SCEN_LST" as "Z_SCEN_LST", "Z_PROD_STD" as "Z_PROD_STD", "Z_AT_LST" as "Z_AT_LST", "Z_SSTD" as "Z_SSTD" 
where "BAL"."DATE_ID" = "CT"."DATE_SK" and "CT"."YID" = 'FY20' and "BAL"."ACCOUNT_ID" = "Z_ASTD"."ACCT_ID" and "Z_ASTD"."LID" = 'TOTAL' and "BAL"."AID" = "Z_AN_ACC_STD"."AID" and "Z_AN_ACC_STD"."LID" = 'NA' and "BAL"."SCID" = "Z_SCEN_LST"."SCID" and "Z_SCEN_LST"."LID" = 'ACTUAL' and "BAL"."PID" = "Z_PROD_STD"."PID" and "Z_PROD_STD"."LID" = 'TOTAL' and "BAL"."AT_ID" = "Z_AT_LST"."AT_ID" and "Z_AT_LST"."LID" = 'NA' and "BAL"."SID" = "Z_SSTD"."SID" and "Z_SSTD"."LID" = 'TOTAL' 
group by "CT"."YID", "Z_ASTD"."LID", "Z_AN_ACC_STD"."LID", "Z_SCEN_LST"."LID", "Z_PROD_STD"."LID", "Z_AT_LST"."LID", "Z_SSTD"."LID";
```

Partitioned explain plan -> https://explain.depesz.com/s/d4FA

Non-partitioned explain plan - https://explain.depesz.com/s/cdT6

From partitioned plan - huge mismatch between estimated and actual.
Nested Loop (cost=0.43..48,683.81 rows=693 width=1,061) (actual time=0.314..2,508.966 rows=2,063,913 loops=1)

Is postgres getting confused and not getting right estimates due to partitioned tables? Please advise.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key problem is the same in both queries: the huge underestimate of the join result. In the partitioned case, PostgreSQL materializes intermediate results, which are much bigger than expected and cause temporary files to be written.  So increasing `work_mem` sould speed up that case.

Join row count estimates are hard to estimate correctly, so it will be difficult to cure the problem at the root. You can fight the symptoms though:

- create indexes on `"Z_PROD_STD"`, `"Z_ASTD"` and `"CT"` that include additional columns, so that you get a much faster index only scan

  For example, to speed up the index scan on `"CT"` that is repeated 2 million times, you could create an index like

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ON "CT" ("DATE_SK", "YID");
  ```

  and then `VACUUM "CT";`.
- alternatively, set `enable_nestloop` to `off` for the duration of the query to reduce the impact of the bad estimate

Comment: Do you mean indexes on these columns (a) Seq Scan on "Z_ASTD"  (cost=0.00..119.69 rows=375 width=10) (actual time=0.060..1.820 rows=375 loops=1) Filter: (("LID")::text = 'TOTAL'::text) (b) Index Scan using "CT_PK" on "CT"  (cost=0.28..0.30 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=2063913) Index Cond: ("DATE_SK" = "BAL"."DATE_ID") Filter: (("YID")::text = 'FY20'::text) (c) Index Scan using Z_prod_std_pk on "Z_PROD_STD"  (cost=0.29..0.31 rows=1 width=11) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1031251)Index Cond: (("PID")::text = "BAL"."PID")Filter: (("LID")::text = 'TOTAL'::text)

Comment: I have added an example of what I mean.